# unknown attribute while uploading csv file rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

When I try to upload a csv file I get the following error message:

```
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError in KontoumsatzsController#import
unknown attribute '﻿weg;wertstellung;umsatzart;buchungsdetails;auftraggeber;empfaenger;betrag;saldo' for Kontoumsatz.
```

My model:

```
class Kontoumsatz < ApplicationRecord
    attr_accessor :weg, :wertstellung, :umsatzart, :buchungsdetails, :auftraggeber, :empfaenger, :betrag, :saldo

    def self.import(file)
        CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
            Kontoumsatz.create! row.to_hash
        end
    end

end
```

My controller:

```
  def import
    Kontoumsatz.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to kontoumsatzs_path, notice: "Erfolgreich importiert"
  end
```

Schema table:

```
create_table "kontoumsatzs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "weg"
    t.string   "wertstellung"
    t.string   "umsatzart"
    t.string   "buchungsdetails"
    t.string   "auftraggeber"
    t.string   "empfaenger"
    t.decimal  "betrag"
    t.decimal  "saldo"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
  end
```

My routes:

```
  resources :kontoumsatzs do 
    collection { post :import }
  end
```

The file I am trying to upload is a CSV UTF-8(comma delimited) (.csv) file.

row.to_hash does not seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How does your CSV file looks like?

Comment: Nice. Everything in german :)

Comment: @Rohit I cannot get it displayed here nicely, but it is an excel sheet saved as an csv file. When I try to copy/paste the data it does not show any comma's. Don't know if that makes a difference :)

Comment: @Fabrizio not my native language, so spelling mistakes are easy to make ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV - comma separated values. Comma in it stands for ',' ;)

So if you are going to use a delimiter other than a comma, you need to specify it. We do this using the `col_sep` option passed for the `foreach` of the CSV.parse. Its like this...

```
class Kontoumsatz < ApplicationRecord
    attr_accessor :weg, :wertstellung, :umsatzart, :buchungsdetails, :auftraggeber, :empfaenger, :betrag, :saldo

    def self.import(file)
        CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, col_sep: ';') do |row|
            Kontoumsatz.create! row.to_hash
        end
    end

end
```

This should help you parse your CSV file delimited using `;`.

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes it is just too easy. haha. All working now.

Comment: I know, made it many times my self, thats why I saw it straight away :P

Comment: I checked the ruby documentation of this `CSV` class and I really wonder why they don't explain this clearly 
 http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html

Comment: I know it from experience, I think I'd used it like 20 times in the last 6 years as a Ruby dev. But I just checked the doc and in the second paragraph it says it "For example, :col_sep, :row_sep, and :quote_char must be transcoded to match your data"